# Monthly Paypal Payments with Bootstrap Pricing Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have a nice Bootstrap Pricing Slider which originally came from here: http://amirolahmad.github.io/bootstrap-pricing-slider/

In my Bootstrap Pricing Slider i have "total amount" after all the math, and i get a score which says the total.

I have "Process" button which normally does nothing and doesn't forwarding to anywhere.

I want that when i get the total score and click on "Process" the amount will replicate into paypal payment and the button will forward me to paypal to pay and will include the amount that display on the total score. I need it for mounthly and annually payments.

Here is the whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap Pricing Slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="price-box">

        <form class="form-horizontal form-pricing" role="form">

          <div class="price-slider">
            <h4 class="great">Amount</h4>
            <span>Minimum $10 is required</span>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div id="slider"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="price-slider">
            <h4 class="great">Duration</h4>
            <span>Minimum 1 day is required</span>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div id="slider2"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="price-form">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="amount" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Amount ($): </label>
              <span class="help-text">Please choose your amount</span>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="hidden" id="amount" class="form-control">
                <p class="price lead" id="amount-label"></p>
                <span class="price">.00</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="duration" class="col-sm-6 control-label">Duration: </label>
              <span class="help-text">Choose your commitment</span>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="hidden" id="duration" class="form-control">
                <p class="price lead" id="duration-label"></p>
                <span class="price">days</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="style">
            <div class="form-group total">
              <label for="total" class="col-sm-6 control-label"><strong>Total: </strong></label>
              <span class="help-text">(Amount * Days)</span>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="hidden" id="total" class="form-control">
                <p class="price lead" id="total-label"></p>
                <span class="price">.00</span>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Proceed <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right" style="padding-right: 10px;"></span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <img src="images/payment.png" class="img-responsive payment" />
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>

        <p class="text-center" style="padding-top:10px;font-size:12px;color:#2c3e50;font-style:italic;">Created by <a href="https://twitter.com/AmirolAhmad" target="_blank">AmirolAhmad</a></p>

      </div>

    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#slider").slider({
              range: "min",
              animate: true,
              value:1,
              min: 10,
              max: 1000,
              step: 10,
              slide: function(event, ui) {
                update(1,ui.value); //changed
              }
          });

          $("#slider2").slider({
              range: "min",
              animate: true,
              value:1,
              min: 1,
              max: 365,
              step: 1,
              slide: function(event, ui) {
                update(2,ui.value); //changed
              }
          });

          //Added, set initial value.
          $("#amount").val(0);
          $("#duration").val(0);
          $("#amount-label").text(0);
          $("#duration-label").text(0);

          update();
      });

      //changed. now with parameter
      function update(slider,val) {
        //changed. Now, directly take value from ui.value. if not set (initial, will use current value.)
        var $amount = slider == 1?val:$("#amount").val();
        var $duration = slider == 2?val:$("#duration").val();

        /* commented
        $amount = $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" );
        $duration = $( "#slider2" ).slider( "value" );
         */

         $total = "$" + ($amount * $duration);
         $( "#amount" ).val($amount);
         $( "#amount-label" ).text($amount);
         $( "#duration" ).val($duration);
         $( "#duration-label" ).text($duration);
         $( "#total" ).val($total);
         $( "#total-label" ).text($total);

         $('#slider a').html('<label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> '+$amount+' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></label>');
         $('#slider2 a').html('<label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> '+$duration+' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></label>');
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is targetted towards the Paypal API.. Have you tried looking into that ? https://developer.paypal.com/ I have updated your tags just so you get more targeted views.

Comment: I really dont know what to look

Comment: Are you using and server side system ? Such as PHP, C# etc ? Or you would just like to generate through javascript ?

Comment: I would like to generate it via javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to edit the `update()` function to write the value into a PayPal form. For example;

Add this into `update()` function near the bottom (after the math has been worked out)

```
$("#paypal_amount").val($amount);
```

Then add the PayPal form

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions" />
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="MyEmailAddress@gmail.com" />
 <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
 <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="" id="paypal_amount" />
 <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="D">
 <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://example.com/paypal-return" />
 <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://example.com/paypal-cancel" />
 <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://example.com/paypal-notify" />
 <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF" />
 <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/x-click-but20.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yk6fkh1s/2/

<sub>**Note:** Paypal does have a [subscription and recurring payment documentation](https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_subscr_techview_outside) which I'd advise you read. The form above will create a subscription for *x* days.</sub>

Comment: I change the email value at the paypal form to my email address, i choose a "plan", i click on the Paypal Subscribe Button, and nothing happens. It is not forward me to the Paypal payment screen. Why is that?